# Audio tag doesn't work in Firefox and Opera

Tags: html, firefox, audio, opera

I'm trying to create my own audio player. I've checked it in Google Chrome  and everything is working good. But when I try to use it in Firefox and Opera (last versions) it does not. For example I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <div id="play">click me</div>
    <audio class="tr_audio">
       <source src="ogg/track1.ogg" type="audio/ogg; codecs='vorbis'">
       <source src="track1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg; codecs='mp3'">
    </audio>
    <script>
        $("#play").click(function() {
            $("audio").get(0).play();
            alert($("audio").get(0));
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

It work's fine in Chrome, but doesn't work in Opera and Firefox. Why?

Comment: Can you play your ogg files normally? (i.e. not in the browser?)

Comment: Opera and FF use the ogg file. Are you sure the path to the ogg file is correct? Do you have your server MIME types set up correctly for ogg files? Do you have an example on the web?

Comment: Yes guys, files plays ok without browser and path is correct. Also if I launch this ogg files with Opera or FF (with right click on file) it plays ok too.. TimHayes, I test it from my computer

Comment: Did you ever get this to  work in Opera?  I've the same problem, but no solutions yet (only for Opera - all other browsers work just fine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your code and testing it in firefox made it clear that the problem was the codecs. The following lines were copied from the firefox console log:

> [10:20:19.068] Specified "type" attribute of "audio/ogg; codecs='vorbis'" is not supported. Load of media resource Example.ogg failed. @ http://example.com/
>
> [10:20:19.068] Specified "type" attribute of "audio/mpeg; codecs='mp3'" is not supported. Load of media resource Example.mp3 failed. @ http://example.com/

Then, removing the `codecs` specification from the `type` attribute made it work in Firefox, Safari and Opera.

```
<audio class="tr_audio">
   <source src="ogg/track1.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
   <source src="track1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

I hope it helped. Cheers

Comment: If an answer is correct, please mark as so, otherwise stackoverflow won't ever know that your problem has been solved. Consider up vote answers that were somewhat useful. This helps other users with similar questions to find answers more easily

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up, anyone using the beta version of FireFox 21, if you haven't noticed MP3 audio now plays in `<audio>` tags without having to edit the about:config of the browser. Now we just need it released properly!

Answer (score 0):

Firefox 24.0 as of Halloween 2013 through firebug 1.12.4 from MP3 source

```
<source src="media/SoundFile.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />

[! Yellow Warning] Specified "type" attribute of "audio/mpeg" is not supported. Load of media resource media/SoundFile.mp3 failed.
```

Originally I tried various codec entries and it really didn't like them. For instance Ogg errored similarly until I removed the codec declarations.. so that idea didn't help.

I think I'm just documented that even though MP3 is suppose to be supported since version 21 in Firefox, it's still not working here for some reason.

Um I should mention this is from a local file at this time, so maybe something to do with the MIME type missing on Win7 or something comes to mind.

**No wait a darn minute here... now I think it's a simple licensing issue.**

So really it's bad error logging it should explain if licensing is the problem.